# How to discover what Linux distribution is in use

Tags: linux, operating-system

Sometimes I need to access some servers running Linux (or maybe another Unix-like SO), but I don't know how to verify which [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) is in use on the server (there are times that even the "responsible" person for the server doesn't know).

Is there an easy and reliable way to discover that, one that is uniform and consistent across all of them?

Comment: @Peter: Was there really a need to change ‘distro’ to ‘distribution’?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`lsb_release -i` may work for you.

More detail is available with `lsb_release -a`

Some discussion at http://etbe.coker.com.au/2007/08/30/identifying-the-distribution-of-a-linux-system/

Comment: lsb_release -d gave a much better result for me. -i gave "Distributor ID: CentOS". -d gave "Description: CentOS release 5.2 (Final)".

Answer (score 31):

```
cat /etc/*release
```

Most distributions put a release file in `/etc/` (like `/etc/redhat-release`, `/etc/gentoo-release`, etc.) which usually has the version number of your distribution in it.

Comment: `- bash: lsb_release: command not found` but `cat` worked for me

Answer (score 9):

This is, annoyingly, a harder problem than it appears.

For Linux systems, use lsb_release.

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 8.04.1
Release:        8.04
Codename:       hardy
$ lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
```

This has the limitation that lsb_release works only for Linux releases.

For all Unix systems, you can also parse up uname.

```
$ uname -a
Linux blue-laptop 2.6.24-21-generic #1 SMP Tue Oct 21 23:43:45 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux
```

You can find some information about the systems and distributions at the [uname Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname).

Comment: More narrowly, `lsb_release` only works on Linux systems which attempt to adhere to the [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) specifications.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask yourself if you really need to know which distro is in use (perhaps because you want to build a package specific for this distribution). In many other cases it is a far better idea, to just test and see if the features you need are there or not. This might look like a lot more work because you have to test every feature one by one but this way, your software becomes far more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

There are different commands you can use to check which distribution is in use. Here I am mentioning only 5 of them.

1. > lsb_relase -a

`lsb_release` provides distribution-specific information. Whereas `-a` display all information about the distribution. You can also use `-d` which only shows the description.

2. > uname -a

`uname` also provides system information. Whereas `-a` display all information. You can use `man uname` for other options.

3. > cat /etc/*release

You can also use `cat` command to print out all specific release information from **etc** folder. This command actually reads the **lsb-release** and **os-release** files from the **/etc** folder.

4. > cat /etc/issue

This command reads the **issue** file from the **/etc** folder.

5. > cat /proc/version

This command reads the **version** file from the **/proc** folder. **/proc** folder contains information about system process.

Answer (score 1):

In my `.cshrc` I have

```
setenv DISTRO `sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/)).*//' /proc/version`
```

For [ksh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) / [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) users, I presume it translates to

```
export DISTRO=`sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/)).*//' /proc/version`
```

and of course this may not work for your favorite distribution. (I have had issues with [Oracle's Unbreakable Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux#RHEL_compatibility) giving something similar to Redhat, but it was good enough for my purposes.)

**Update August 2016** I have not used Linux in this way for a while (2008 is a long time ago). It seems that this does not work anymore for the systems I now have.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the /etc/issue usually has something about the distribution in use.

But I don't know about its availability on all distributions.

Comment: Unfortunately, many distros have a very minimal /etc/issue which just has something like "This is \n.\O (\s \m \r) \t" in it, which gives no real information about the distro.

Comment: Yep, it works on Ubuntu. I got "`Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l`". Yes, \n and  \l are literal (not ASCII 13 and 10).

Answer (score 1):

The [proc file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs): A directory in Linux with all the hardware level information. So just type

```
cd /proc/
```

There you will find a gold mine of information stored in a text file for all the arbitrary information about the system.

Comment: So `cat /proc/version` will return information about the version.

Comment: `cd /proc` by itself does nothing useful.  You don't have to `cd` to a directory to read the files there, and normally should not need to (though in an interactive shell, it saves you from typing long paths; but scripts generally rarely need `cd`).

Comment: Many files in `proc` use C strings, so they are not technically pure text.  Try `tr '\000' '\012' <file` to replace the nulls with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'uname':

```
[anton@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost 2.6.26-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 26 21:15:43 UTC 2008 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3000+ AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

Comment: uname shows the version and architecture, but not the distribution (Red Hat, SuSE, Ubuntu, ....)

Comment: normally the distribution adds to the version, like in the example the distribution is Arch Linux. And for Arch, all the other mentioned ideas except /etc/issue don't work as well. So why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -r
```

should print the kernel version currently running (at least, it does for Linux, don't know
if it's the same for *BSD or others). That's not the same as the distro but the kernel version often includes the distro name if it's customised, like "2.6.27-gentoo-r1" or something.

Init often prints something at boot, but that's not much good when it's running.

Otherwise as far as I know there isn't anything universal.

Answer (score 0):

### NeoFetch

... is a quite professional **BASH script** that should have all the info you might desire.

(*Disclaimer:* I am not affiliated with it)

#### Usage

```sh
neofetch --stdout | grep '^OS: ' | sed -e 's/OS:[[:space:]]\+//'
```

might give:

> Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64

but there is much more info.

#### Installation

Options:

1. system packaage `neofetch`
2. If that is not available, either see the [official installation instructions](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Installation)
3. or for a hacky one-time use - if you have faith and an internet connection - you could use:

   ```sh
   wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/master/neofetch' \
       && bash neofetch --stdout \
       && rm neofetch
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try `uname -a`