# C++ get linux distribution name\version

Tags: c++, linux, distribution

According to the question " [How to get Linux distribution name and version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320401/how-to-get-linux-distribution-name-and-version) ", to get the linux distro name and version, this works:

```
lsb_release -a
```

On my system, it shows the needed output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:    9.10
Codename:   karmic
```

Now, to get this info in C++, Qt4's QProcess would be a great option but since I am developing without Qt using std c++, I need to know how to get this info in standard C++, i.e. the stdout of the process, and also a way to parse the info.

Uptil now I am trying to use code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127567/linux-c-run-and-communicate-with-new-process/4127696#4127696) but am stuck on function [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)().

Comment: what are you having trouble with? starting the external process from C++? reading its output? ... please be more specific and show what you have so far.

Comment: found answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315666/c-get-linux-distribution-name-version/6316023#6316023

Comment: Be aware that lsb_release is not installed by default on all systems.  Some (like CentOS 7) need it to be installed explicitly.

Comment: For Fedora 31 the release version is in /etc/redhat-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it from cplusplus.com forums, a simple call `GetSystemOutput("/usr/bin/lsb_release -a")` works.

```
char* GetSystemOutput(char* cmd){
        int buff_size = 32;
    char* buff = new char[buff_size];

        char* ret = NULL;
        string str = "";

    int fd[2];
    int old_fd[3];
    pipe(fd);


        old_fd[0] = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
        old_fd[1] = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
        old_fd[2] = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

        int pid = fork();
        switch(pid){
                case 0:
                        close(fd[0]);
                        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                        close(STDERR_FILENO);
                        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                        dup2(fd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
                        system(cmd);
                        //execlp((const char*)cmd, cmd,0);
                        close (fd[1]);
                        exit(0);
                        break;
                case -1:
                        cerr << "GetSystemOutput/fork() error\n" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                default:
                        close(fd[1]);
                        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

                        int rc = 1;
                        while (rc > 0){
                                rc = read(fd[0], buff, buff_size);
                                str.append(buff, rc);
                                //memset(buff, 0, buff_size);
                        }

                        ret = new char [strlen((char*)str.c_str())];

                        strcpy(ret, (char*)str.c_str());

                        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
                        close(fd[0]);
        }

        dup2(STDIN_FILENO, old_fd[0]);
        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, old_fd[1]);
        dup2(STDERR_FILENO, old_fd[2]);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Half the time this doesn't work, it just hangs.  Any idea why?  Also, isn't 'buff' a memory leak since you never free it?

Answer (score 27):

You can simply use the function:

```
int uname(struct utsname *buf);
```

by including the header

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
```

It already returns the name & version as a part of the structure:

```
   struct utsname 
   {
       char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
       char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined network" */
       char release[];    /* OS release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
       char version[];    /* OS version */
       char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
       #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
          char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
       #endif
   };
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: actually this is implemented already. I need to know the distribution name and version e.g. "Ubuntu" or "Fedora" etc.

Comment: Since my program is only running on Ubuntu systems, the answer combined with this one helped me:
http://askubuntu.com/a/517140/17800

Answer (score 5):

For recent linux distros you can use following to get the OS info. The output is pretty standard and can be parsed using following spec:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Sample outputs:

```
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="27 (Twenty Seven)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=27
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 27 (Twenty Seven)"

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"

NAME="Arch Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"
ID=arch
ID_LIKE=archlinux
ANSI_COLOR="0;36"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int writepipe[2];
if (pipe(writepipe) < 0) {
  perror("pipe");
  return 1;
}
int ret = fork();
if (ret < 0) {
  perror("fork");
  return 1;
}
else if (ret == 0) // child process
{
  dup2(writepipe[1],1); // set writepipe[1] as stdout
  // close fds
  close(writepipe[0]);
  close(writepipe[1]);
  execlp("lsb_release","lsb_release","-a",NULL); //TODO: Error checking
}
else // parent process
{
  int status;
  waitpid(ret,&status,0); //TODO: Error checking
  //do what you need
  //read output of lsb_release from writepipe[0]
}
```

It works for me

Comment: How do you read the output of lsb_release from writepipe?  Writepipe is a very small buffer, you can't be serious if you mean writing to and getting the return from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are files named /etc/*version* and /etc/*release* which have information like whether you're using Ubuntu or Fedora, etc. (which is what the OP clarified his question to be).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12, and those files don't exist.  So this doesn't seem like a good option if it's not a portable solution for Linux.

Comment: I found `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/debian_version`, interestingly enough. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like the uname solution posted by @Alok Slav, but in case it helps someone who needs to use a command-line utility to get the info, consider using [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: Doesn't work.. uname returns "Linux" on my Debian linux system. I want "Debian"; or "Ubuntu". Or "Red Hat" &c.

Comment: @RobinDavies looks like you're commenting on the wrong answer.  The 'uname' answer is above.

Comment: I'm commenting on you personally liking an answer that doesn't address the OP's question so nobody needs to waste time following the link. Alok's answer has already been tagged as wrong. . ;-) No harm no foul..

Comment: @RobinDavies It works for me on Debian 9:  `$ uname -a
Linux debian9-zb17m2 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux`