# Figure out Linux OS name from utsname

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to get the Linux OS name (e.g. something like 'Ubuntu 16.04', 'Ubuntu 14.04' etc) from a c++ code. I came to know about utsname and tried to use it. But the values in the struct fields sysname, release, version etc are too descriptive and I want something simple (like 'Ubuntu 16.04', 'Ubuntu 14.04' etc). Is there some document available that maps the values in the utsname struct to some simple names?

Value of utsname struct's fields:

```
sysname: Linux
nodename: ubuntu16-server
release: 4.4.0-130-generic
version: #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 29 23:11:20 UTC 2017
machine: x86_64
```

Comment: I think this post might be usefull. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315666/c-get-linux-distribution-name-version

Comment: What programming environment do you code on?

Answer (score 1):

try this command in terminal:

```
    cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

or this:

```
    cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

I don't know on what programming environment you code.. so you might need a `Process` to execute and return the terminal command and then you need to parse the output. (Parsing can be done also with the cat command in terminal if you want)

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, obtaining the system information as well as parsing shall be from the compiled program. Spawning a system shell is of course possible, but neither a good nor the intended solution.

Comment: I am aware of this solution. But my question is different; I specifically want to use utsname to arrive to OS name, possibly with the help of some mapping from the values in utsname struct to OS names.