# How do I identify the particular Linux flavor via command line?

Tags: linux, version, command-line-interface

I'd like to be able to detect which particular Linux flavor is installed on a computer, e.g., [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) vs. [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux), via a command line command.

Some people recommend [`uname -a`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname), but that only reports the kernel version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find os name and version in Unix/Linux platform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26988262/608639), [How to discover what Linux distribution is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/264290/608639), etc.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Try the below command....
It worked for me...

```
cat /proc/version
```

Once you know that you are running Red Hat for example, you can get to the point with:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Or on Debian:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

or in general :

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Also you could use the following command

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Comment: cat /etc/*-release is it work on all Linux flavours? like Cent OS, Ubuntu, Debian etc.

Comment: It should work ...but it doesn't then try other options that I have provided.

Answer (score 23):

For displaying details including release and codename of the distro

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

Comment: ... or Arch Linux.

Comment: Does `cat /etc/os-release` work?

Answer (score 6):

`cat /etc/os-release` is the command that worked for me. It displays information in the following format:

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="21.1 (Vera)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 21.1"
VERSION_ID="21.1"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=vera
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

As `ddelange` and `Stuart` mentioned in the comments, you can also use it like this:
`source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME`
which outputs:
`jammy`
and `source /etc/os-release && echo $ID_LIKE`
which outputs:
`ubuntu debian`

Comment: a handy shorthand: `source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME`

Comment: sourcing & echoing `$ID_LIKE` seems reliable for the flavour

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```bash
echo $(lsb_release -si)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

Comment: Why would you need to `echo` a subshell output, isn't that redundant?

Comment: @nomæd Yes, do `lsb_release -si`, echo is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try `hostnamectl`. It lists the operating system, CPE OS Name, Kernel, Architecture, etc.

Comment: only for systemd based systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Use command to know the name of the os:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```