# how can i know on which flavour of linux i was using through command

Tags: linux, unix

It is possible that i should know the flavor of Linux through command-line

if i run the following command

> $ uname -s
>   output is
>
> Linux

it just showing "Linux" and but not flavor name of Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I identify the particular Linux flavor via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036048/how-do-i-identify-the-particular-linux-flavor-via-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find os name and version in Unix/Linux platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988262/best-way-to-find-os-name-and-version-in-unix-linux-platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `cat /etc/*-release` ?

Other commands that might work:

```
cat /etc/system-release # I believe mostly Red Hat based distro

cat /proc/version
```

Comment: upvote for /etc/*release ; definitely not oracle-release or /etc/issue

Comment: @MacHala don't know how did i get that 'issue' there. Oracle was a misinterpretation from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

on most distros should work the command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the shell to know the distribution/flavour of linux.

1. `lsb_release -a` to check the current distribution of linux.

Additionally you can run the following to know more details about the underlying linux kernel.

2. `uname -a` - to know the linux kernel-version whole info
3. `uname -r` - to know the linux kernel-version