# Installing Python on a remote UNIX machine

Tags: python, unix, installation, remote-access

I need to run a Python script on a remote Linux machine. The problem is that Python isn't installed on that machine. As a newbie in Linux greedily taking advantage of the user friendly tools Ubuntu offers, I have no clue how to install it without a packet manager (God bless apt-get!). I don't even know if the OS running on the remote machine is Debian based, but I do know that it doesn't have apt-get installed.

I connect to it using SSH, have root rights, want to run my scripts on it continuously.

Please help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264290/how-to-discover-what-linux-distribution-is-in-use

Comment: I find it hard to believe there's any Linux machines without some version of Python installed. It's integral to many system utilities.

Comment: Just a guess: The machine might use the `yum` package manager. This post is slightly off-topic for this particular site, though.

Comment: paste output of uname -a you will be able to see what *nix flavor your a dealing with

Comment: @DanielRoseman I remember installing it on my Ubuntu myself too. I think there are Linux distributions without Python

Comment: @bernie Sorry about the inconvenience, I am new to this forum as well. Why is that, the topic isn't relevant? Just so I don't repeat the mistake

Comment: No need to apologise. Judging by folk's responses this post falls in a gray area: it may or may not be considered off-topic depending on how you look at it. Either way, I'm glad you got your issue solved. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as a *normal user* run the following commands:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.tgz
cd Python-2.7
./configure --with-pth --with-dec-threads --with-signal-module --prefix=/opt/python-2.7
make
```

then as *root* do (becoming *root* using `sudo` or `su`):

```
make install
```

**A brief explanation**:

- `wget` downloads the python sources, you can install another version if you like, maybe python 3.x
- `tar` uncompress the downloaded file
- `configure` checks if all required dependances are available and configures the source code for your own system
- `make` starts the compiling/linking process
- `make install` copy the compiled file in the right place

after that maybe you need to make a symbolic link to your python executable or to your python folders, it depends on you

**references**: 
- the installations commands have been copy-pasted from this [website](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/web_development/python/installation/how_to_download_compile_and_install_python.php) after a rapid google search, so maybe you need different config options
- the [official info are here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#getting-and-installing-the-latest-version-of-python)

**note**: 
I this question should be better placed on [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com) (the reason is that may be more relevant for [computer enthusiasts & power users rather than for programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), since it is not a programming issue but a software installation issue)